# Check the status of an application pool (IIS 6) with C#

Tags: c#, iis-6, application-pool

How can I check the status of an IIS6 application pool with C# ?
For example, I want to know if it is running or not !
Thank's in advance for your help !

Comment: You can find this on link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349532/an-application-which-fetches-iis-and-app-pool-details-of-website-hosted-in-remot/48164885#48164885

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524962.aspx

You can do this checking the AppPoolState Property:

```
 protected void status()
    {
        string appPoolName = "dev.somesite.com";
        string appPoolPath = @"IIS://" + System.Environment.MachineName + "/W3SVC/AppPools/" + appPoolName;
        int intStatus = 0;
        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry(appPoolPath);
            intStatus = (int)w3svc.InvokeGet("AppPoolState");
            switch (intStatus)
            {
                case 2:
                    lblStatus.Text = "Running";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    lblStatus.Text = "Stopped";
                    break;
                default:
                    lblStatus.Text = "Unknown";
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Above code is running, but this need more information as its giving an error of "Access Denied". Can you make some light on it.

Comment: @KartikGoyal: Disable firewall from AdministrativeTools-->Windows Firewall and Advanced Setting works for me.

Comment: Above Code helped me to find the details. I have updated the above method in below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349532/an-application-which-fetches-iis-and-app-pool-details-of-website-hosted-in-remot/48164885#48164885

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the services of [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257340%28VS.80%29.aspx) (
Windows Management Instrumentation)

There are several articles around on how to manage IIS using WMI via vbscript, e.g.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/163/managing-applications-and-application-pools-on-iis-70-with-wmi/

If you take one of those articles you should be able to adapt it to C# easily enough.