# IIS6 App Pool state

Tags: c#, asp.net, application-pool

I was wondering if there is a way to capture the state of an IIS6 App Pool using DirectoryEntry in C#?

I have seen people use AppPoolState for IIS7 but is there an equivalent that will work for IIS6?  Or do I need to use a different namespace?

EDIT: Is there anything that will display a string for status?  AppPoolState looks like it only accepts integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you'd use the same property: [Check the status of an application pool (IIS 6) with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478495/check-the-status-of-an-application-pool-iis-6-with-c/2478532#2478532)

Comment: I don't want to assign an app pool name.  I would like to get all App Pools on the server.  I have this statement which currently allows me to get all app pools.  using (DirectoryEntry appPoolsEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("IIS://{0}/W3SVC/AppPools", serverIP)))
{
foreach (DirectoryEntry childEntry in appPoolsEntry.Children)

Comment: this works great when getting all app pools from a specific server.  However, when I integrate my code into the code that was posted, it will not work without assigning a specific app pool.